# C# HttpWebResponse not seeing cookies

Tags: c#, cookies

I'm trying to log in to Yahoo! using an `HttpWebRequest`, but i'm having trouble getting the initial cookie that they set. I'm not sure if this is a problem with my `Request/Response`, if they set the cookie in some nefarious way to prevent this kind of activity.

So here's the first part of my `Connect()` method, which to start with simply gets the login page, so I get the authentication hidden fields and cookies:

```cs
    public void Connect()
    {
        var LoginUrl = "https://login.yahoo.com/config/login";
        var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

        // First get a login page to grab some important values
        var request = WebRequest.Create(LoginUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        Console.WriteLine(request.SupportsCookieContainer);
        var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse; /* LINE:30 */
        var loginPageText = string.Empty;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            loginPageText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

If I inspect the `response` object at line 30, I don't even see any `Set-Cookie` headers. If I visit the same page manually in Chrome, I see the following header being sent back:

```
Set-Cookie:B=bgg40ppbditpf&b=3&s=4s; expires=Mon, 05-Mar-2018 11:53:19 GMT; path=/; domain=.yahoo.com
```

What could cause those headers to not appear?

Comment: @RJK is there a policy about forcing contractions in questions these days?

Comment: Cool. Absolutely no man. I thought it might improve some readability. Isn't improved? Also not only contractions, additionally i have done some improvements. Didn't I? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no cookies either, but if I fake being a browser:

```
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.75 Safari/537.36";
```

`response.Cookies[0]` is set.

Comment: Ah, they're blocking based on the UA. I'll try that, thanks!